# How to bind a custom directive attribute value to an isolated scope in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
    app.directive('myCustomAttr',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            valueOfAttr : "@myCustomAttr"
        },
      };
});
```

How would I pass the value of the attribute? Thus far, I've only found examples that use restrict : 'E'.

```
<input type="text" my-custom-attr="myValue" />
```

So, if I were going to bind "myValue" to the scope, how would I do that?

[EDIT]

Sorry, I had a typo. I was using the my-custom-attribute correctly, but it still doesn't seem to bind in the directive.

Comment: <input type="text" my-custom-attr="myValue" />

Comment: valueOfAttr : "=myCustomAttr" should provide two way binding. Not my code, see: http://jsfiddle.net/bcaudan/SbrKj/

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you want `=myCustomAttr` instead of `@myCustomAttr`. There's mention of this under ["Isolating the Scope of a Directive"](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). There's also more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21071821/297468).

Answer (score 0):

use the link function:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
   var myAttr = attrs["myCustomAttr"];
}
```